# flan-t5-xxl: ValueError: Need either a `state_dict` or a `save_folder` containing offloaded weights

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I tried to run flan-t5-xxx model from Hugging Face both in my Mac M1 and Google Colab, both have the same error:

`ValueError: Need either a state_dict or a save_folder containing offloaded weights.`

The code from Model Card:

```
from transformers import T5Tokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-xxl")
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-xxl", device_map="auto")
input_text = "translate English to German: How old are you?"
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to("cuda")
outputs = model.generate(input_ids)
print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For who need:

Create a folder (name save_folder for example).
Then update:

```
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-xxl", device_map="auto")
```

to

```
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/flan-t5-xxl", device_map="auto", offload_folder="save_folder")
```