# Hugging face model.pretrained not able to find model weights

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, huggingface, llama

model name: meta-llama/Llama-2-70b-chat-hf

I am new to this and trying to run a huggingface model using pretrained function. Model is loading cache of more than my disk space so I changed the default HF_HOME variable location due to the cache issue and now I am not able to run the model and getting this error.

````
    raise ValueError("Need either a `state_dict` or a `save_folder` containing offloaded weights.")
ValueError: Need either a `state_dict` or a `save_folder` containing offloaded weights.```


I want to know if I am missing some configurations?
````

Comment: checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76617863/flan-t5-xxl-valueerror-need-either-a-state-dict-or-a-save-folder-containin